# Angular - ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in same Component

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have a simple **Angular 5** application with a **HttpInterceptor** that notifies a service when a request is made. Components can subscribe to this service to get this information.

Full example with error here => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5b86se

In my *AppComponent* I want to show a loading indicator when request are made in my child component (*HelloComponent*).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingIndicatorService } from './loading-indicator.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div *ngIf="loading" style="color:red">pretend this is loading indicator</div>
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>`
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
   loading: boolean = false;

   constructor(private loadingIndicatorService: LoadingIndicatorService) { 

    loadingIndicatorService
      .onLoadingChanged
      .subscribe(isLoading => this.loading = isLoading);
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has
>   changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value:
>   'true'.

If I'm correct this error appears when a child component changes a value in a parent component.

But my child component (*HelloComponent*) is only doing a HttpGet and the **HttpInterceptor** is changing the parent component (*AppComponent*) over a service with an observable.

Shouldn't changing over a service be the correct solution here? 
Can someone explain why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 7):

It throws an error because your variable loading gets updated when `onLoadingChanged` is called. This means your initial value got changed.

I would suggest you to read more about **[**`here`**](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)**

The general fix for this would be,

```
    constructor(private loadingIndicatorService: LoadingIndicatorService,private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { 
    loadingIndicatorService.onLoadingChanged.subscribe(isLoading => {
       this.loading = isLoading
       this.ref.detectChanges();
    });
 }
```

Comment: Should this be done here? In this GitHub issue (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17572#issuecomment-364175055) someone from the Angular team wrote that only 5% of the time this is the correct solution.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and it worked but what I meant is that even if it works it isn't always the correct solution to the problem. Usually this means that something is wrong in how you setup your Angular application.

Comment: I do not think its an issue with the setup

Comment: This fixes the problem indeed, in the worst possible way IMO, but doesnt answers OP question. Why is the error thrown?

Comment: hmm ! if you know the best way post it :) i would also like to know! probably attached link will help OP

Comment: @Sajeetharan @Shamshiel Wrapping update code with setTimeout does the job. Is it better? I don't know but it is another solution. Example from my code `setTimeout(() => this.appService.onNotify(false));`. As I could understand Angular change detection does not play well with Interceptors by design. I guess that was the reason why we had to wait so long for Interceptors although they were prominent feature of AngularJS

Comment: Suggested edit queue is full but link should be: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Answer (score 5):

The `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` gets thrown (in developer mode) when an expression changes more than one time during one change detection lifecycle. So how is it changing in your example?

Lifecycle #1:

- `loading: boolean = false;` during the constructor of `AppComponent`
- The hello component makes the http request in `onInit`. This then triggers the the interceptor which updates the observable.

Lifecycle #2 (in dev mode, to check whether all values are stable / still the same):

- `loading` is now `true` because the subscription to the observable changed the value, which is different than the previous value of `loading = false`, so Angular throws the error.

To mitigate the problem, you can:

- move the code from `onInit` to the constructor. downside: it's not recommended to do stuff in the constructor
- include cdr as Sajeetharan describes. downside: you'll have to do this on every client of your observable.
- emit the changed observable value after a timeout `setTimeout(() => myObservable.next(...));`. downside: it's ugly. However it might cause you the least trouble if you expect multiple clients to subscribe to your observable, as you don't have to include cdr everywhere.

To be honest, none of those solutions are particularly pretty.

Note that the `async` pipe has nothing to do with the problem as suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncPipe to the rescue:

```
<div *ngIf="loadingIndicatorService.onLoadingChanged | async">Loading...</div>
```

Remember to change the service into public.

**Edit:** Needed to also set changeDetectionStrategy to OnPush. Working blitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ay1ikq

As for why this is happening without OnPush even with AsyncPipe, can't say. Maybe someone with deep knowledge into Angular core? CD triggered internally right before/after interceptors? I almost always use OnPush but there has to be a situation where I didn't at first, and still haven't seen this error happen with AsyncPipe. Only thing really different from anything I've done is using interceptors to do something that causes a change in a value bound to a template, so that's got to be the root cause?

Comment: I get the same error when I use the async pipe. :/ you can try it in my stackblitz example.

Comment: I don't see async pipe in the blitz you linked. I'll take a better look later when on pc, but looks like you might wanna use async on posts too in the other component.

Comment: I tried it in the Stackblitz but I didn't save the changes, so you can't see the pipe. Yesterday someone posted a similar answer as you and deleted it afterwards because it doesn't seem to work with the async pipe. Sadly I don't know why :/

Comment: changeDetectionStrategy to OnPush and it works. Seems without that there's some useless change detection cycle going on. Fixed fork:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ay1ikq

I also changed the EventEmitter to BehaviorSubject though it doesn't really matter in this case, but you'd expect the loading state to have an initial state of false so it's just more logical to me as a B-Subject. :)

Comment: Anyway, I recommend to always use OnPush (it should be the default imo!). It "forces" you to think about CD and learn how to structure your app "the right way" from the get go, or at least the most performant way, using unidirectional data flow etc.

Comment: I'm using both `OnPush` and `async` pipe, bot for some crazy reason still getting an error in a very similar case. It looks like there is more to this problem than it seems.